# EDIT<select> with ng-options doesn't refresh selected on when changing $scope

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, drop-down-menu

I have my select like this :

```
<select ng-model="exportParam" 
        ng-options="item as item.lib for item in allExportParams | orderBy:'lib'" 
        class="form-control">
</select>
```

I save its state in `stockOptions` in the service to display it when you go back on the page later. (a quick-fill sort of) :

```
export: function (params, criteres, options) {
            stockParams = options.saveAllparams;
            stockCriteres = criteres;
            stockOptions = options;
            console.log(options);
            $http.post(urnPrefix + '/exports?export=true', angular.toJson({'params':params,'criteres':criteres,'options':options}), {responseType: 'arraybuffer'}).success(function (data) {
                var blob = new Blob([data], {
                    type: "application/xlsx"
                });
                //saveAs provided by FileSaver.js
                saveAs(blob, 'export-' + new Date().getTime() + '.xlsx');
            });
        },
```

The saving is made and is working fine. The problem is when I want to load it.

I do it like this :

```
$scope.exportParam = exportService.getStockOptions().groupParam;
```

It works, `exportParam` is the option selected in the `<select>`.

**But**

It's displaying the default value. I mean the `<select>` is blank. The good value is selected, I can see it with a debug, but it's displaying the options like none are selected.

If someone already had this problem and can help that would be awesome.

EDIT : It's working the second time I save the value. After that it's displayed perfectly everytime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the ngModel and the ngOptions dont hold the same value (or values from the same object).

To overcome this issue use [track by](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) in ngOption expression.

track by can be any unique attribute to identify that object.

Comment: I get `Error: [$rootScope:infdig]`. I can't use that method, already tried before... :/